# T-SQL: I want to get result in like in second screenshot

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

[image]

**[strong text][3]**
[image]

This is my problem case in which we have have to group partner ID on the basis of thire and and assign them a rank ID.

Here some rank ID have same group count and same partnerid we want to identify them and remove them.

Desired result should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to `select` the `distinct` rows?

```
select distinct groupcount, partnerid
from tbl
```

---

test setup:

```
create table tbl (RankId int, GroupCount int, PartnerId int);
insert into tbl values 
 (1,2,316),(1,2,329)
,(2,2,316),(2,2,329)
,(3,3,316),(3,3,329),(3,3,319);

select distinct GroupCount, PartnerId
from tbl;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CXTE98698

returns:

```
+------------+-----------+
| GroupCount | PartnerId |
+------------+-----------+
|          2 |       316 |
|          2 |       329 |
|          3 |       316 |
|          3 |       319 |
|          3 |       329 |
+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: in rank ID column there are 3 rank ID with their count and corresponding partnerID also now I want to remove duplicate same count number and partner ID.  Just like in image 2

Comment: I was looking something else.